# Live Code Editor Codemirror - Live Preview Won't Execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a code editor with live preview (like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)) that I can use on my chromebook offline.

However, when I load it in the browser, live preview works fine, but as a chrome app it won't update the `iframe`. You can view the source on [Github](https://github.com/mikethedj4/Live-Code-Editor-for-Chrome).

Does anyone know the cause and any workaround?

This is the what shows up in the developer console of the extension.

```
unload is not available in packaged apps.___________________________extensions::platformApp:17  
document.open() is not available in packaged apps.__________________extensions::platformApp:17   
Uncaught Error: document.write() is not available in packaged apps.    ____extensions::platformApp:31
```

This is the problem...

```
function updatePreview() {
  var previewFrame = document.getElementById("preview");
  var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
  preview.open();
  preview.write('<style type="text/css">' + cssEditor.getValue() + '</style>'); 
  preview.write(htmlEditor.getValue());
  preview.close();
}
```

Comment: Are errors not clear enough? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated

Comment: Expecting people to surf through a repo to guess why something isn't working isn't reasonable. At least create a demo in a sandbox where people can use dev tools to see what's going on

Comment: updated question with code. (thought I added it, but guess not.) Sandbox demo would be irrelevant as this problem only exists in a chrome app.

Comment: When making packaged apps, you can't use document.write() or document.open(). You also can't use alert(), and a whole bunch of other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors are quite clear in their wording.

There is a number of Web APIs that are disabled for the Chrome Apps platform.

> Though Chrome Apps use the web platform, some web features have been disabled or else are used in a different way. Mainly this is to avoid security issues and to improve programming practices.

The full list is available at [Disabled Web Features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) documentation, with workaround suggestions.

You will need to adapt your code to Chrome Apps platform; there's no general magic recipe.